# How can I manage a tmux session using supervisord?

Tags: linux, services, wget, tmux

I want do mirror the data of some 15 different servers that aperiodically but continuously provide files that I need.

For this, I created a tmux conf that opens 15 tmux-windows with shells that run wget or other programms for the indiviual downloads in loops (so they are polling).

I want to be able to attach to the tmux to see the progress of the downloads or debug them. Furthermore I want to be able to start, restart, and stop the downloaders+tmux all at once.

Unfortunatelly I am bound to use supervisor 3.0.
Can I somehow configure the tmux-server to kill all windows on exit or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmux kill-session` will kill a particular tmux session and all child processes, but leave the tmux server running.

```
kill-session
         [-a] [-t target-session] Destroy the given session, closing any
         windows linked to it and no other sessions, and detaching all
         clients attached to it.  If -a is given, all sessions but the
         specified one is killed.
```

`tmux kill-server` will do the above to all session on that tmux server and then kill the tmux server itself.

```
kill-server
         Kill the tmux server and clients and destroy all sessions.
```

You may also need to set up a wrapper script to start and stop tmux, rather than having supervisor do it directly. [See this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9803987/3342206).